# Authorization has been denied for this request

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

I have created a webapi with Basic OAuth and a mobile app using ajax to access the api. I set the AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan to be 1 day as coded below.

```
static Startup()
{
    PublicClientId = "self";
    UserManagerFactory = () => 
      new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>());
    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
        AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/UserAccount/ExternalLogin"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
        AllowInsecureHttp = true            
    };
}
```

Everything works fine in my local pc until I deployed it on the hosting site.

My app can login and received the new token and with this token the app (for every 2 seconds) is able to access the webapi for a whole day until the token expired.
But if I stops the app (without stopping the app) from accessing the webapi  for 5 to 6 minutes, and then I starts it again, I will get a "401 - Authorization has been denied for this request." and need to request for a new token.

Now, since it works in my PC, is there anything that I missed out that could cause this denied eg Session, cookies, setting in the host system etc ?

FYI My PC is using IIS7.5 and Host system is powered by PleskWin and using IIS8.5

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to play around the Plesk and found a setting under ASP.Net Configuration for Website > Session setting > Authentication mode, I changed it from original "None" to "Windows" and it works. After 5 to 6 minutes, it does not give me the error as I stated before.
Just for info, under same section, there is also a Session timeout (minutes), it is set as 20 and I have not changed it from the start of deployment.

I am still not sure what this setting does or what relationship it does with IIS. Can anybody enlighten me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am dealing with exactly the same problem, but my setting is allready on 'Windows' but I can not get it to work properly.

Changing the settings here (ASP.Net Configuration for Website), result in invalid connectionstrings, because it is not writing the web.config well. 
Can you tell me if your web.config changed after changing this setting ("None" to "Windows")?
Do you know if your provider has had these problems before?